# How can I navigate to a directory name with a special character

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Normally, I'm used to navigate into directories in Linux using the `cd` command. Now, in a terminal, I need to get into a directory named `-`.

I tried to navigate into the directory using `cd -`, but I was brought to the previous directory instead, which is the normal behavior.

How can I navigate into a directory named `-`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preceding the directory name with `./`, as in `cd ./-`, and using the full path, as in `cd /path/to/-` work. Of course, you could also rename the directory, which is recommended, or create a symbolic link to it and `cd` into the symbolic link instead, as in `ln -s - ./something ; cd something`.